# Can I connect dual displays on Thinkpad W541?

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, vga, thunderbolt

I am getting a new [Thinkpad W541](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T3OCVCO), 16GB. I am planning to install Ubuntu latest on it. The laptop comes with a VGA and Thunderbolt ports.

So I am wondering if I can connect multiple monitors, one through thunderbolt port (using thunderbolt-HDMI adapter) and other through VGA, to extend the displays? Anyone tried this setup? Will this work?

Comment: I have no experience with thunderbolt ports of your laptop but you could try a live usb and check if it works before you install it.....You can make a live usb with UNetBootin.

Comment: You should be able to, and also to use a DisplayPort MST hub since it has DisplayPort 1.2

Comment: Thunderbolt?  Do you mean Displayport?

Comment: It seems this laptop combines the Thunderbolt and mini Displayport into one connector.  You may want to update the question to say mini Displayport to not confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with thunderbolt but I am confident that what I know can help you. First connect your cables to your monitor and computer. Now go to settings:[image: settings]

Now select Displays:[[image: Displays[2]]

You should see a screen like this:[image: Display_Menu]

One of the problems that I faced when I first set this up was that resolution becomes much bigger on the original monitor. It will take a little work but you want to check the menu that says "Mirror displays (May limit resolution options)."

Also under General options make sure that "All displays" is the menu that shows.

Finally, click "Apply" You will be asked if you wish to keep these settings. You are all set, and the next time you connect your computer you will not have to do this again.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen multiple monitor ports work and not work on different latops.  This is something that is entirely dependant on the particular implementation of the chipsets on a particular laptop.  There is no rhyme or reason for this feature, so you need to get this information from either the supplier or Lenovo.

The Nvidia Quadro K2100M chipset does support up to 4 monitors.

With an ultradock, a maximum of 3 displays can be run simultaneously. (Page 107--labelled number--in the manual.)  But there is no indication on whether the VGA and mDP/Thunderbolt ports can be used simultaneously on this model series in the manual.

Your best bet would be to contact the reseller and ask them, or get the exact model number and contact Lenovo direct.  Lenovo's website is not clear, and Lenovo does not offer a document with the exact specifications and features.  I checked Lenovo's sales and support sections.

My advice is: Do not buy Lenovo.  They are a rubbish company to deal with, this being just one example.

https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t540p_w540_w541_ug_en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be work. I try it yesterday on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have W541 with NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] / Quadro K1100M/PCIe/SSE2